# How to modify variables outside of their scope in kotlin?

Tags: variables, kotlin, scope

I understand that in Kotlin there is no such thing as "Non-local variables" or "Global Variables" I am looking for a way to modify variables in another "Scope" in Kotlin by using the function below:

```kotlin
class Listres(){
var listsize = 0
fun gatherlistresult(){
    

    var listallinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                     .getReference()
                                     .child("MainTimeline/")
                                     .listAll()
    listallinfo.addOnSuccessListener {
        listResult -> listsize += listResult.items.size
    }
                
    
}
}
```

the value of listsize is always 0 (logging the result from inside of the `.addOnSuccessListener` scope returns 8) so clearly the `listsize` variable isn't being modified. I have seen many different posts about this topic on other sites , but none fit my usecase.

I simply want to modify `listsize` inside of the `.addOnSuccessListener` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to bridge some asynchronous processing into a synchronous context. If possible it's usually better (in my opinion) to stick to one model (sync or async) throughout your code base.

That being said, sometimes these circumstances are out of our control. One approach I've used in similar situations involves introducing a `BlockingQueue` as a data pipe to transfer data from the async context to the sync context. In your case, that might look something like this:

```
class Demo {
  var listSize = 0

  fun registerListResult() {
    val listAll = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("MainTimeline/")
        .listAll()

    val dataQueue = ArrayBlockingQueue<Int>(1)

    listAll.addOnSuccessListener { dataQueue.put(it.items.size) }

    listSize = dataQueue.take()
  }
}
```

The key points are:

- there is a blocking variant of the `Queue` interface that will be used to pipe data from the async context (listener) into the sync context (calling code)
- data is `put()` on the queue within the `OnSuccessListener`
- the calling code invokes the queue's `take()` method, which will cause that thread to block until a value is available

If that doesn't work for you, hopefully it will at least inspire some new thoughts!

Comment: Yes. Given the mix of sync and async processing, your options are limited to blocking or polling. This is one of the reasons why I suggested sticking to one paradigm if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This method will always be returned 0 as the `addOnSuccessListener()` listener will be invoked after the method execution completed. The `addOnSuccessListener()` is a callback method for `asynchronous` operation and you will get the value if it gives success only.

You can get the value by changing the code as below:

```
class Demo {

 fun registerListResult() {
     var listallinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                     .getReference()
                                     .child("MainTimeline/")
                                     .listAll()
    listallinfo.addOnSuccessListener {
        listResult -> listsize += listResult.items.size
        processResult(listsize)
    }
    listallinfo.addOnFailureListener {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
     }
 }

 fun processResult(listsize: Int) {
    print(listResult+"") // you will get the 8 here as you said
 }
}
```

Comment: You may get an error while processing. Updated answer. added `addOnFailureListener() `callback too. please you reached inside error by debug

Comment: We can discuss it further , but this doesn't solve my issue , and keeping in mind we are using kotlin. acessing listResult in the processresult function doesn't work

Comment: list result isnt defined inside of the process result function, so the value cannot be printed.

Comment: and the idea is to get list size to be changed to the value of listResult.items.size , which isnt working in this example either.

Comment: Updated answer by passing the variable to process result function

Comment: This still don't solve my issue , since Your solution is only printing the value... If thats that case , I could have just printed the value inside of onclicklistener. I am looking to have a value that I can reference  in the program , not just view it on the console... Your processresult method is redundant.The first approach you had : Creating a class variable and using a class function to modify it, is the type of solution i am looking for. since I can always reference the that value in the program

Comment: Then use that method. Printing means just to show how can we get the value

Comment: look at my code example. and tell me does it work for you